# Domain authenticated video links, prevent video link sharing

Tags: authentication, wordpress, amazon-s3

I'm running WordPress and I have s2member pro plugin. 
I have videos that I'd like any body to watch on my website and only on my website, I realize that they could record or capture the screen, it doesn't matter for me, I just want to prevent anybody from downloading the video, share a link to it, or even copying the link and paste it on another page, again, I just want them to be able ONLY to be able to watch it on my website. 
I did a lot of research and the results are the following:

- Most people when you ask them this question, they answer: haha no body could prevent something streamed online from being recorded, well that's not my question, I don't have any problem if the viewer did that, good luck with that. So I didn't get any clear answer how to do that on WordPress anywhere
- AmazonS3/cloud-front, could be integrated with s2member. I came to a result that perhaps that's possible using amazon S3, for example, you upload the video file to amazon bucket, then you set the ACL for that video to "only authenticated users", then you generate a URL to that video and post it wherever you want on your website, as long as that URL are opened on your website, amazon will create session i.e, any viewer on my website is an authenticated to watch the video as long as they're on my website; in that URL, there is a parameter to determine how long a link to that video would be good for sharing or viewing on a place other than my website, for example, you may set it to 5 seconds; in that case, if anybody copied the URL, and tried to open it somewhere else, they will get an error, because the 5 seconds would be ended by that time. 
  Well, it's pretty straight forward how to create amazonS3 account, and it's also the case for changing the permissions of the video, however, I don't know and I don't understand how to generate such URLs, I searched a lot but I didn't get sane results/tools/plugins whatsoever.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: I understand your frustration, but this isn't really a security question. Perhaps you might get better results if you shifted your question a little. What you are asking for is pure authentication. Why not have a login on your site? Why not use an iFrame and only allow the iFrame referer access to the video? Have you investigated how Vimeo does it?

Comment: [This link](http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html) may help you